# rspec needs to be installed in base app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rspec, rake

I am having trouble building a gem. When I run rake it gives the the following error message:

> You need to install rspec in your base
>   app

I'm not completely certain what I should be doing to fix this. I have double checked that rspec is, in fact installed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, I installed the gem from gemcutter and it worked fine. Still not 100% sure what this error message is referring to. Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a decent indepth tutorial on setting up rSpec. Even though you need to install rSpec into gems, you also need to set it up in the actual app.

http://www.pmamediagroup.com/2009/04/tutorial-install-rspec-rails-factory-girl/

Answer (score 1):

Have you run the following command

```
script/generate rspec
```

This will build the necessary infrastructure for rspec